# What language (or framework) can i use to build auto do some specific task in a website

Tags: automation, frameworks

I want to write a program to do some specific task in a website (ie: Auto order, auto login and post some comments). But i don't know what language or framework can help me do that. 
If you know plase help me.

Comment: Try googling browser automation. Selenium is an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to automate some user actions on a website, for that [Selenium/Webdriver](https://selenium.dev/) is the best library/framework if you want to do it on a Desktop or [Appium](http://appium.io/) if you want to do it on mobile.

Seeing as you are a beginner I would also recommend to use Python as its not only easy to get started with but its also one of the better languages in current times for anything related to automation.

I actually have multiple playlists that teach:

- [beginner to senior concepts in Selenium](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLK7KNOA7vbPOK1Ih3SXyaM1VnWut5Tn17)
- [beginner Appium concepts](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLK7KNOA7vbPNyT-9Zo0ij-iKDCQq7A0BM)
- [how to build an advanced framework in Appium](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLK7KNOA7vbPOh_2sx4aKnU0y6DDUFtQaW)